# Multi-platform "easy" window programming

Tags: user-interface, mono, window

i'm thinking about programming a tool that would be useful in windows and mac (as we use those at work) and it's 100% necessary that is inside on a OS window.

The first thing that came to my mind was to use java - as it's cross platform - but, is there any alternative to program cross platform window based programs?

Has anyone tried to use C# windows forms with Mono in other OS's?
I'm interested in a garbage collected language if possible as I don't want to think about possible memory leaks for a tool that can be slower or faster without any trouble.
Also if it's possible to be as easy as it is in visual studio + C# it would be awesome!

Any idea will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is fine if you're comfortable with it.

Many languages have bindings to cross-platform toolkits: for example Python is very pleasant and has PyQt4 or WxPython, both of which can be used to make GUIs which work nicely on Windows or Mac.

In the manage-your-memory world, using Qt from within C++ is actually very pleasant (they have a nice API). I find it creates more elegant applications than my Java code (they feel a tad more native) though YMMV.

Comment: I've finally started the project with Qt after trying to use Swing (which feels very old and clunky in my opinion) and i'm very happy with the results. I recommend Qt over Java